# three col with equal height image and tagline not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code with a screen attached.

As you can see there are 3-col with the image and title but they are not aligned either their padding is the same.

The overall section is on the left side and has a lot of space from the right.

Any idea how to make them equal in height and width?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-XWTTruHZEYJsxV3W/lSXG1n3Q39YIWOstqvmFsdNEEQfHoZ6vm6E9GK2OrF6DSJSpIbRbi+Nn0WDPID9O7xB2Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div id="section-top-homepage">
  <!-- vission -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="whitecolor">
      <img alt="" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="3afd4d82-63ca-4046-b77c-1d3815e959cf" src="/tilesw/sites/default/files/inline-images/vision.svg" />
      <h3 class="top25">Vision</h3>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- objectives -->

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="whitecolor">

      <img alt="" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="6e0a289f-a866-4d46-81c8-6f2f6aceecd8" src="/tilesw/sites/default/files/inline-images/objectives.svg" />
      <h3 class="top25">Objectives</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- mission -->

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class=" whitecolor">

      <img alt="" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="aeaa7c28-c987-4174-a2c2-5fa45de0ab83" src="/tilesw/sites/default/files/inline-images/mission.svg" />
      <h3 class="top25">Mission</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use bootstrap, but the red section showing the three icons has the following code which i think affected the entire row content not be organized.

```
section#block-counterboxstyle3 { 
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e00021;
    clip-path: ellipse(550% 100% at 400% 100%);
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap ?

When you set a class like col-4, you only set the width of each bloc, you need to set a max-heigth on css or in tag IMG using height.

Example:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the wrapping div with id `id="section-top-homepage` to 100% of the page. You can confirm this by setting its border to `1px solid red`. This worked for me.